# Does hair in front of the head create a chatziza issue with Tefillin Shel Rosh

Tags: halacha, tefilin, hair, chatzitzah, head

I personally grow out my hair a bit in the front of my head. A chup I believe it’s called.

I’ve heard from different people that this is Halachically unacceptable as it presents a problem when wearing Tefillin as it is a Chatziza (interposition).

Any sources to back that claim up?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37784/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/75300/759 the "deal" is some people who don't like long hair for other reasons quote that minority opinion a lot more than you'd otherwise expect

Answer (score 2):

R Daniel Mann from Eretz Hemda answers your question at length [here](https://eretzhemdah.org/newsletterArticle.asp?lang=en&pageid=48&cat=7&newsletter=723&article=2665). He concludes it is not an issue in most cases although he does bring opinions (Machatzit Hashekel, [Mishna Brura 27:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.27.4?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.27.15&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en)) that raise the issue of much more hair than normal and/or the tefilin sitting on so much hair that it doesn't sit on the head anymore. See [there](https://eretzhemdah.org/newsletterArticle.asp?lang=en&pageid=48&cat=7&newsletter=723&article=2665) for details.

The summary of his answer is

> Some poskim say that long hair is a chatzitza for tefillin. However,
> regarding most cases of long hair, these opinions are difficult, and
> the length is not the main issue, as we will see.
>
> One puts the tefillin shel rosh where the hair grows (Shulchan Aruch,
> Orach Chayim 27:9). As one is not required to shave his head
> frequently, hair could not possibly be a chatzitza regarding tefillin. [...]
>
> In summary, in all but the most extreme cases presented above, there
> is ample reason to say that long hair does not prevent the fulfillment
> of the mitzva of tefillin. We would note that many of the poskim who
> raised the issue combat the phenomenon of long hair for males
> (primarily?) based on other halachic, social, and philosophical
> elements (see Bemareh Habazak V, 25).

Answer (score 0):

I heard once in a shiur that as long as the hair is growing in its natural position that it is not an issue. I don't recall who gave the shiur, but they commented that they personally push the hair on the front of the head forward before putting on their Tefillin. But if the hair is folded back, as is often done with a chup, and the Tefillin is resting on the part that's folded back it would be an issue since it's not the natural way for the hair to grow.